# Почему падает ядро при записи в массив?

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

возникла проблема. Имеется код в программе:

```
field db '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'
move resb 1

_move:
        mov edx, 1
        mov ecx, move 
        mov ebx, 1
        mov eax, 4
        int 0x80

        mov     eax, move
        mov     ebx, field
        add      ebx, eax

        call     _clear

        mov     [ebx], byte 'X'

        ret
```

Опытным путём, узнал, что call _clear выполняется, а вот при подставке 'X' в [ebx] падает с сообщением:
23988 segmentation fault (core dumped)
В move поступает число с помощью ввода, программа запрашивает его, и пользователь вводит число от 1 до 9
Если же вместо строки:

```
add ebx, eax
```

Написать:

```
add ebx, 2
```

То всё корректно выполняется, как я подозреваю, проблема в том, что ввод с строки не является числом, а ASCII символом, но не знаю как его обработать и вообще, так ли это, надеюсь на вашу помощь, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Когда Вы с консоли вводите число 2, в регистр попадает скорее всего ее аскии код (в данном случае 50) и происходит выход за пределы массива. И конечно, это может закончится падением. Если Вы уверенны в пользовательском вводе, то просто вначале нужно вычесть код нуля (48) и потом делать сложение.

то есть

```
sub eax, 48
add ebx, eax
```

Comment: Да, я тоже так думал, но к сожалению, продолжает падать. Мне подсказали "move - 1 байт, а в eax вы суете (и потом складываете) 4. Конечно, там мусор оказывается ", но не совсем понимаю, как мне очистить его, или что с ним сделать

Comment: @Fr3nD А вот мне больше `mov ebx, field` не нравиться. ebx же 4х байтовый, и когда вы делаете такой такой mov, то в нем оказывается 0x04030201 (массив то у вас db и это отдельные байты). И да, надо чистить регистр `xor ebx, ebx` после чего заполнять только младший байт `mov bl, field`

Comment: @Mike, при заполнении bl возникает ошибка
перемещение обрезано по месту: R_386_8 у неопределённого символа «.data»

Comment: @Fr3nD Однако в nasm весьма придирчивый синтаксис ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46928566/relocation-truncated-to-fit-r-386-8-against-bss похоже, что надо писать `mov bl, [field]`. Но если это так, то mov eax, move загружает в eax вообще адрес move. И что то я сомневаюсь, что вы действительно хотели прибавить вот ту 1 из массива field к адресу move. Так что серьезно разберитесь как в вашем ассемблере пишется загрузка адреса и как загрузка значения по адресу. после того как разберетесь надо пересмотреть весь код